# How should I safely replace Central Vacuum faceplates?

Tags: electrical, replacement, central-vacuum

The covers for the faceplates of my central vacuum system have started to break off from age. How do I safely replace these? These are technically wired for electricity right? Is this a job for an electrician?

This central vac system is one of the older ones where the powered floor brush plugs into its own outlet external from the faceplate.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the brush gets power from a separate outlet, then more than likely the voltage going to the vacuum outlets is very low (maybe 5v), just enough to detect a connection.  But it doesn't hurt to shut the breaker off to the central vacuum, if for no other reason than to keep the thing from turning on and sucking up your screws.